# onblur function call in zend framework add element

Tags: zend-framework

I am new to fend framework. I have a input box in html with on blur property which call a ajax function code is given below:

```
input name="companyCode" type="text" id="companyCode"  style="width:220px"                              
onblur="getOrganizationode(this.value);"
```

and a ajax script tags.

Basically i want my input box in Zend form with onblur function call in Add element function like this

```
addElement(   'text',    'companyCode'     ,    array(          
            'required'   =>     true,
            'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
            'style'    => array('width:220px'),
```

so please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the call to the attributes:

```
addElement('text', 'companyCode', array(    
    'required'   =>  true,
    'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
    'style' => array('width:220px'),
    'onBlur' => 'getOrganizationode(this.value);'
);
```

Comment: This will work but it is an obtrusive practice. If you want it attached there just leave it, but the other way to go is to attach it on the client side in a [unobstrusive manner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).